# on the server side, how to tell the received data is either of textbox1 or textbox2 of client side using named pipes?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, named-pipes

I am working on c# wpf application. I have created a sample client and server using named pipes. On the client side application i have created two textboxes: textbox1 and textbox2. I have also created the same two textboxes as textbox1 and textbox2 on server side application. I want to send data from client side textboxes to server side textboxes just like copying. But i get confused how i would recognize that the received data from client is of textbox1 or textbox2?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create 2 named pipes, one for each textbox. But that is probably an overkill.

Another option is to have some kind of prefix for the data you send through the pipe which will help you understand it's origin on the other side.
For instance you can prefix each data with the number of the textbox, delimit it with a pipe "|" and then the rest of your data.

So a "Hello World" from TextBox1 will look like this:

```
1|Hello World
```

where one from TextBox2 will look like this:

```
2|Hello World
```